# I need to continue image upload to Firebase Storage in the background even when the browser tab is closed

Tags: angular, firebase, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I have an Angular Firebase progressive web application that serves a purpose of upload/download images to a server. I need the app to continue uploading/downloading the images to **Firebase Storage** even when the user closes the browser.

I am using the default service worker package. Is it even possible, if so, how?
P.S: I am new to PWA and don't know much about service workers.